# DAPR Actor lifetime - graceful stop

Tags: lifetime, actor, dispose, dapr

Lets suppose I have a DAPR actor implementation, which covers a long running operation implemented in single threaded loop. The actor has two responsibilities:

- when actor creates - it also creates the single thread loop
- when actor operation is called - its wakes up the single thread loop

Something like this:

```
// there can be only one TenantActorWorker
// services.AddTransient<ITenantActorWorker, TenantActorWorker>();

public class TenantActor : Actor
{
    private ITenantWorker _worker;

    public TenantActor(ActorHost host, ITenantWorker worker)
        : base(host)
    {
        this._worker = worker;
    }

    public void Process(String tenantId)
    {
        _worker.WakeUpOrStartFor(tenantId);
    }
    
    // ??? how to implement this ??? - there is no "StopActor" like method
    public override void StopActor()
    {
       _worker.Cancel();
    }
}
```

The worker instance is implemented as is, not important here. The important thing is, that I must warn it that the actor becomes deactivated - so also stop processing the long operation . Is there any notitications for actor instance to warn it before deactivates (or worst: being relocated)?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the `protected override Task OnDeactivateAsync()` does the trick.